# Joomla! Unable to edit modules PHP codes

Tags: php, joomla, joomla-extensions, virtuemart, joomla-module

I'm quite new to Joomla! as well as PHP.
Currently i'm developing a Joomla! site using Joomla! Version 1.5.14.

I have downloaded and installed VirtueMart 1.1.3 on my site and now i want to edit the registration fields for the VirtueMart Module.

I went to C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\modules\mod_virtuemart and opened up the mod_virtuemart PHP script.

I only see these codes for the registration part:

```
<?php endif; ?>
    <?php if( $mosConfig_allowUserRegistration == '1' ) : ?>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2">
            <?php echo $VM_LANG->_('NO_ACCOUNT'); ?>
            <a href="<?php $sess->purl( SECUREURL.'index.php?option=com_virtuemart&amp;page=mysite.registration' ); ?>">
            <?php echo $VM_LANG->_('CREATE_ACCOUNT'); ?>
            </a>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <?php endif; ?>
```

But i'm unable to find the few lines of codes for the registration fields (For the user to key in).
Examples: Email, company name, title, first name, last name, etc... (with the text boxes beside them)
Hope you get what i mean.

Now i want to add in some more fields for registration, such as 'Position in company', etc..
Can anyone tell me specifically where to find those codes so that i can edit them?

Comment: Why 1.5.14? I too would prefer to use 1.5 over the latest short term releases (until 1.8 comes out), but that's not the latest even for 1.5 series. IIRC, you should upgrade to the 1.5.23, as it features important bug and security fixes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my knowledge you should do it from admin panel. Joomla provide custom settings of fields for virtuemart user registration.

You also can refer below link for that.

http://virtuemart.net/documentation/User_Manual/User_Registration_Fields.html

I think this would be helpful to you.

Let me know if anything new you get.

Thanks.

Comment: I have a question. My codes are hosted on my website. But now that i wanna make changes, i put the codes into XAMPP so that i can run them locally and test it out first before i put them up into the internet. The problem is, whenever i clicked on "Manage user fields", it redirects me to the website. If i edit from there, the changes will be made straightaway on my site (which i don't want to). May i know which files and what are the codes that i should change so that when i click on "Manage User Fields', it will still be in locally?

Comment: Actually its seems like your baseURL still refer your live site URL.so you need to change the baseURL to set your local machine. its may be in configuration.php file..Thx

Comment: I can't find 'baseURL' in the configuration.php file.